# How to use ESPAsyncWebServer with SoftwareSerial communicating ESP01f

Tags: esp8266, led, wifi, arduino-uno-smd

I'm creating a web server with using host.com/?ll="some". But I read that I can use for it ESPAsyncWebServer for this things. And how can I use it without flashing esp? If possible give me link to the libraries.

Comment: You read wrong. That library is only for running *on* the ESP8266. You can *only* use it by directly writing software for, and flashing, the ESP8266. You can't use it by communicating over SoftwareSerial.

Comment: OK. Thanks...........